# Is olfaction same among different individuals?

Tags: biochemistry, olfaction

For instance if I smell the fragrance of a rose, well it smells like roses (little bit sweet).  But is that smell the same for other people?

Because we also have different voices, why not have different olfaction.

Comment: The substance that you smell is very likely the same as other people (the smell receptor on the nose react to the same chemical), however how your brain reacts to a certain smell is very likely different to other people - so the perceived smell can also be different

Comment: @Nicolai thank you! Can you move your comment to the awnser box so I can accept is as an awsner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humans generally have the same set up of [olfactory receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_receptor), since they are encoded by genes (there likely are minor differences between people, since there are a lot of these genes). Therefore chemically or physically  all humans can smell the same substances.
However, how a smell is perceived depends also a lot on how the brain reacts to a certain smell (or rather the activation of certain olfactory neurons). Therefore individual people can *perceive* the same chemical substance a different way - how different depends probably strongly on previous experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Humans actually have a wide diversity in the range of odors they can detect. [1],[2] The variations are dependent on a number of factors, including age, sex, pregnancy, training, and individual genetics. [3],[4],[5],[6]

A significant source of genetic variation in olfactory function between individuals comes from the fact that quite a few chemical-sensing genes have in recent evolutionary times become defective in some gene variants while remaining functional in others.  An individual's inheritance of a particular combination of functional and nonfunctional olfactory receptor genes gives the individual an personalized combination of smelling sensitivities. [1]

[1] Menashe, I., Man, O., Lancet, D. and Gilad, Y., 2003. Different noses for different people. *Nature genetics*, 34(2), p.143. [PDF](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/molgen/members/lancet/publication/pap103_NG_Noses_main.pdf)

[2] David G. Laing, Richard L. Doty, Winrich Breipohl, eds., *The Human Sense of Smell*, Springer Science & Business Media, 2012, p. 312.  [Image](https://books.google.com/books?id=OB_yCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA312&dq=smell%20%22interindividual%20variation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF0_HJ28DUAhUJ7GMKHUIJCQQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=smell%20%22interindividual%20variation%22&f=false)

[3] [Odor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odor#Analysis)

[4] A.B. Marin  T.E. Acree  J. Barnard, Variation in odor detection thresholds determined by charm analysis, Chem Senses (1988) 13 (3): 435-444. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1093/chemse/13.3.435

[5] Darren W. Logan, Do you smell what I smell? Genetic variation in olfactory perception., 
*Biochem Soc Trans.* 2014 Aug; 42(4): 861–865. doi: https://doi.org/10.1042/BST20140052

[6] [Simon Makin, Sense of smell has a genetic flavour, *New Scientist*](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21929293-100-sense-of-smell-has-a-genetic-flavour/)